# Await Receiving Warning while in try-catch Block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The first `await` below generates the warning `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression` if I do not include the `.catch` line immediately found after (and currently commented out). However, all the code is included in a try-catch block. Why am I receiving this warning? Isn't the `MongoClient.connect`an asynchronous call?

```
const db = null
async function dbConnect() {
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true})
    // .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
    if (!client) throw new Error("Database Not Available")
    db = await client.db(dbName)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

dbConnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.connect()` returns a promise not a client. Try this code:

```
const db = null
async function dbConnect() {
  try {
    const client = new MongoClient(url)
    await client.connect({useUnifiedTopology: true})
    db = await client.db(dbName)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

dbConnect()
```

Comment: Got it. By using const client = new MongoClient(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true})
await client.connect(), the warning disappeared. Thank you @juicy-g

Comment: Not that the OP's `catch()` block (reproduced in your answer) EATs any errors and does not provide errors back to the caller.  That is usually not good as the caller has no way of knowing if the operation succeeded or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with you, but that is outside of the scope of the question asked regarding the warning and await. I am sure OP will read this and add more code.

Comment: Fixing other things that are wrong does not have to be out of scope of the best answer you could provide.  I routinely fix all sorts of things that are wrong in addition to what the question is about.  That's how you create the best answers.